# Fetching the current retrieve function from an Akka actor from akka-testkit

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka

I have an akka actor that uses logic like this in my retrieve method:

```
become(nextState("some data"))
```

How do I verify that this worked from akka-testkit (i.e. that the new retrieve method is nextState and that "some data" was passed to it)?

thanks

Comment: Send it another message that would only be processed a certain way given that exact state change. I would prefer that as that's more real world vs trying to check what the current receive PF is.

Comment: In theory I completely agree, but the drawback is that it can be tricky to observe the state from the outside, so the test code becomes longer.  The other alternative is to add code to quickly return the status, but that would be adding code to the class just to enable testing, which is also bad. I see that if my actor is a FSM there is a stateName variable exposed...

Comment: Aside from what @cmbaxter said above, the only way would be to use a specific message to ask the actor which state it's in, which FSM provides more cleanly. The "become" behaviors are held in a private stack in the ActorContext, with no outside access whatsoever (sans sneaky/ugly reflection you'd have to do in your test code).

Comment: thanks, I'll look into using FSM directly